# Keeping an image proportion inside of a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I get an image to stay inside the bounds of my flexbox?

- Width and height of image should grow/shrink when box expands so no absolute values.
- Height 100% skews the image when used with width.
- I do not want to hide overflowing content.
- CSS solutions only that work on all browsers.

So basically i'm after something that keeps the image inside it's parent flexbox, maintaining an images aspect ratio.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: gold;
}

.empty {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `max-` values for your **img**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: gold;
  text-align:center;
}

.empty {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but what if the image is smaller than the width of it's parent?

Comment: well will be the max size of the img actually ... @panthro will be bad practice to force the img be more than its original size, pixelated ... if you want that the option could be use the img as background.

Comment: @panthro not sure if I understand but will add this: if the image is going to maintain it's aspect ratio and you have a set height and the containing element doesn't match the image's aspect ratio, there's going to be left over space somewhere.

Comment: DaniP - svg's don't pixelate.

Comment: @panthro you included a PNG in your post and did not mention SVG, so SVG has nothing to do with the question. Are you concerned about the image filling it's container more? That's what I understood your first comment to mean. Please clarify what you meant (or your issue) so we can help provide a proper answer .

Comment: PaniP - no they don't, it's clear you are skirting round the issue as your answer doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: @panthro I'm not I'm just trying to help, Are you exporting your logo as SVG from illustrator for example ? there is the **flexible** option ... Include the SVG part on your question and a real SVG image ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is container's fixed height, remove it and your image should stay inside inner box.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: gold;
}

.empty {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want 40px for container, try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  background: gold;
  text-align:center;
}

.empty {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/07/logo-tv-logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="empty">
  </div>
</div>
```